# PostgreSQL Installation on Ubuntu: 'initdb' Command Not Found

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL on my Ubuntu system, but I keep encountering an issue with the 'initdb' command. After following the installation instructions and running 'sudo apt-get install postgresql', I expected everything to work smoothly. However, when I try to initialize the database cluster with 'initdb', the terminal returns an error saying that the command is not found. I double-checked the installation and even reinstalled PostgreSQL, but the problem persists.

Has anyone else faced a similar problem during PostgreSQL installation on Ubuntu? What could be causing the 'initdb' command to be unavailable, and how can I resolve this issue to successfully set up PostgreSQL on my system? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to install PostgreSQL on my Ubuntu system by running the command 'sudo apt-get install postgresql' in the terminal. After the installation, I expected to be able to initialize the database cluster using the 'initdb' command. However, when I executed 'initdb', I encountered an error stating that the command was not found.

In an effort to resolve the issue, I checked the installation steps to ensure I followed them correctly. When I couldn't find any mistakes, I proceeded to reinstall PostgreSQL, hoping it would fix the problem. Unfortunately, even after the reinstallation, the 'initdb' command remained unavailable, and I was unable to proceed with setting up PostgreSQL.

I'm seeking help to understand why the 'initdb' command is not working and how I can successfully initialize the database cluster during PostgreSQL installation on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: To question **add as text** 1) Postgres version. 2) The repo used. When you did the install a cluster should have already been created. Use `pg_lsclusters` to verify. If you want to create a new cluster use `pg_createcluster`. See my blog posts [Install](https://aklaver.org/wordpress/2023/06/29/postgres-debian-ubuntu-packagingpart-1/) and [commands](https://aklaver.org/wordpress/2023/07/01/postgres-debian-ubuntu-packagingpart-2/) for more info.

Comment: When you follow the Ubuntu manual, you don't use initdb.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that Path variable does not contain defined path.

```
echo path
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

if it is not there set the path by this command:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
```

It may help you.

Comment: No, you don't want to do this. The Ubuntu/Debian packages have a mechanism for creating/working with/deleting Postgres clusters. Doing the above will short circuit that process and make thing worse not better.  Read this [Ubuntu Postgres](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-postgresql) and adapt your answer or delete it.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you are trying to set up a postgres database, after the installation you should run `sudo -u postgres psql` to login with the system user account.
You can now set up postgres and create a new user.

```
postgres=# create database mydb;
postgres=# create user myuser with encrypted password 'mypass';
postgres=# grant all privileges on database mydb to myuser;
```

To learn more you can visit this [blogpost](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/creating-user-database-and-adding-access-on-postgresql-8bfcd2f4a91e)

Comment: He doesn't need initdb to set up a database after installing with `sudo apt-get install postgresql`, initdb this would would have been necessary if he installed postgres using source code

Comment: Read my comments to the first two 'answers'. They and this one do not answer the question. They show a lack of research and no understanding of Ubuntu/Debian  Postgres packaging.